# Unusual Template Behavior with XSL

Tags: xslt

Experiencing some very odd behavior with, what should be, a very simple use of XSL and XSLT.

Here's a code sample.

```
<xsl:template match="check">

<div class="check">

<xsl:apply-templates mode="check">
<xsl:with-param name="checkName">testVariable</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apple-templates>

</div>

</xsl:template>
```

The template called above

```
<xsl:template match="option" mode="check">
    <xsl:param name="checkName" />

    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox">
        </input>

        <label>
            testText
        </label>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Pretty simple right?
It should, for each instance of a  instance in the XML create a checkbox in a  with a hard coded label.

However, what I'm getting is

```
<div class="check"></div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
<div class="check"></div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
<div class="option>Checkbox stuff here</div>
```

Here's some sample XML

```
<check><option key="1"/><option key="0"/><option
            key="0"/><option key="0"/><option
        key="0"/></check>
```

Anyone know what's going on? :D

Comment: The problem is in the information you haven't shown us. This question doesn't provide enough data for anyone to help. Please, provide: 1.The complete (but as minimal as possible) XML document. 2. The complete (but as minimal as possible) XSLT stylesheet. 3. The complete results produced when the transformation provided in (2) is applied on the XML document provided in (1). 4. Explanation what the transformation is expected to do and produce. 5. Explanation why the current results from the transformation seem wrong.

Comment: @bobber205: With your input sample and those **two rules only**, you can't get that output.

Comment: @Dimitre I think I've provided all I can or need to. The current results seem wrong because The <div> is ended before the next div is started. The XSL file in question is quite large and modularized. I think this *may* be everything that is relevant.

Comment: @bobber205: As you can see from my answer (and please, do the transformation yourself, too) your provided code, just wrapped in an `<xsl:stylesheet>` instruction, when applied on your provided XML document, produces completely different results (and I think these are the results you want) than what you provided as results. ??? Please, correct your question.

Comment: The results are get for your transformation are indeed the desired ones. This XSL document is fairly complex but I think I've sectioned out the pieces that could be in question. I honestly don't know what else I could possibly include that would be relavent or ok for me to do so. Is there a way I can check my XSLT processor?

Comment: Coworker has mentioned that in the past we've had trouble with getting unproperly formed XHTML and had to change some settings do it doesn't "auto close" tags. As for processor we're using apache xalan xsl and xsltc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is either in the XML-document/code you haven't shown to us or, less likely, you may be using a buggy XSLT processor.**

**This transformation** (Your code wrapped within an `<xsl:stylesheet>`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="check">
   <div class="check">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="check">
     <xsl:with-param name="checkName">testVariable</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="option" mode="check">
    <xsl:param name="checkName" />
    <div class="option">
      <input type="checkbox"></input>
        <label>testText</label>
    </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<check>
    <option key="1"/>
    <option key="0"/>
    <option key="0"/>
    <option key="0"/>
    <option key="0"/>
</check>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div class="check">
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox"></input>
        <label>testText</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox"></input>
        <label>testText</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox"></input>
        <label>testText</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox"></input>
        <label>testText</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox"></input>
        <label>testText</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I have verified that the transformation produces identical results when run with**:

- Saxon 6.5.4
- MSXML3, MSXML4, MSXML6
- .NET XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform
- Saxon 9.1.05
- AltovaXML (XML-SPY)
- XQSharp

Comment: I've discovered that it's the HTML that's being spit out has errors. The XSLT is giving the intended HTML, it's the intended HTML that is incorrect.

Comment: I've come across this in another very similar situation. The text I'm getting outputted from the transformer is indeed wrong this time. What should I be looking for now in our transformer?

Comment: @bobber205: The first thing is to provide a complete example, to identify the XSLT processor you are using and to ask other people to independently repro and confirm the unwanted behavior. When and if this happens, then the next step is to notify the vendor/developers of the bug.

Comment: I will try to do this in the future. I was able to add a non-breaking space to in my empty span tag and it resolved the issue.

Comment: @bobber205: Yes, usually `<span><xsl:value-of select="$emptyVar"/></span>` produces `<span></span>` , although I have no experience with Xalan.